# How to receive multiple data with getx?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I try passing data from Page A to page B and also passing data from Page X to page B

JobData? job;
UserData? userData;

(From Page A to B with Job data)
`Get.toNamed(route(B), arguments: {"job": job})`

(From Page X to B with Job data)
`Get.toNamed(route(B), arguments: {"job": job, "user": userData)`

and receiving data like:
 user = Get.arguments['user'];
job = Get.arguments['job'];
``

but I am getting errors like:

`Class 'JobData' has no instance method '[]'. Receiver: Instance of 'JobData' Tried calling: []("user")`

how can i receive data in such suitation

Answer (score 0):

it sure will throws an error because from page A to B then page B will call ['user'] and since page A send no data about ['user'] it will throws error cause it null,

you have to add some condition if it null

```
var user = Get.arguments['user'] ?? '';
```